# Serializing a class that contains other classes

Tags: vb.net, image, class, serialization

I have created a custom imagelist class in VB.NET, and I would like to serialize / deserialize it.

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

<Serializable()>
Public Class clsImageList

    Public Images As New List(Of clsImageItem)

    Public Sub Add(ByVal uGUID As String, ByRef uImage As Image)

        Dim nItem As New clsImageItem(uImage, uGUID)

        Images.Add(nItem)

    End Sub
    Public Function Image(ByVal uIndex As Integer) As Image

        Return Images.Item(uIndex).Image

    End Function

End Class
Public Class clsImageItem

    Public ReadOnly Property [Image] As Image
    Private _sGUID As String

    Public Sub New(uImage As Image, uGUID As String)

        Image = uImage
        _sGUID = uGUID

    End Sub

End Class
```

Using a regular ImageList, I did it like that:

```
Public Function ImageListToBytes(ByRef uImageList As ImageList) As Byte()

    Try
        Using ms As New MemoryStream
            Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter()
            bf.Serialize(ms, uImageList.ImageStream)

            Return ms.ToArray
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception

        Debug.Assert(False)
        Return Nothing
    End Try

End Function

Public Sub BytesToImageList(ByRef uBytes() As Byte, ByRef uImageList As ImageList)

    Using ms As New MemoryStream()

        ms.Write(uBytes, 0, uBytes.Length)
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

        Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
        uImageList.ImageStream = DirectCast(bf.Deserialize(ms), ImageListStreamer)
    End Using

End Sub
```

Can somebody tell me how I can serialize / deserialize my clsImageList?

Comment: @RubberDuck The error I am getting is in the line  bf.Serialize(ms, uImageList.ImageStream). "ImageStream" is not a member of clsImageList. What should I use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you should do is marking your `clsImageItem` also `Serializable`.

Then try serialize and deserialize `clsImageList` class. so in your serialization and deserialization methods, pass an instance of `clsImageList` and serialize and deserialize it.

```
Public Function ImageListToBytes(ByRef c As clsImageList) As Byte()
    Try
        Using ms As New MemoryStream
            Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter()
            bf.Serialize(ms, c)

            Return ms.ToArray
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Assert(False)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function

Public Sub BytesToImageList(ByRef uBytes() As Byte, ByRef c As clsImageList)
    Using ms As New MemoryStream()
        ms.Write(uBytes, 0, uBytes.Length)
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

        Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
        c = DirectCast(bf.Deserialize(ms), clsImageList)
    End Using
End Sub
```